# raster2pgsql: "Could not allocate memory for INSERT statement"

Tags: postgresql, postgis, raster

I'm very new to raster2pgsql so please bear with me. I'm trying to load a 60mb .tif (from the High-Resolution Settlements Layer project) to my postgis-enabled database with the following code:

> raster2pgsql -s 5235 -C -F [path to the .tif] public.hrsl_lka | psql
> -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -d project

However, I get the following error:

> ERROR: insert_records: Could not allocate memory for INSERT statement
> ERROR: process_rasters: Could not convert raster tiles into INSERT or
> COPY statements ERROR: Unable to process rasters

Loading smaller .tifs of around 3mb to the same database but from other sources works fine, however.

Is there a size limit with raster2pgsql? I'm on PostgreSQL 12.4.

With many thanks,
Gregor

Comment: hi Gregor. Is it possible for you to provide a link to this raster file of yours? cheers

Comment: Hi Jim! There you go: https://file.io/0B48mnGfwq2K

I gdwalwarped it to EPSG 5235 and then compressed it with gdal_translate. You can find the original file here: https://openafrica.net/dataset/sri-lanka-high-resolution-settlement-layer-2015/resource/a03cc781-b345-49d4-a5de-fd35056fe89c.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the tile size `-t`?

According to the documentation:

> -t: Tile size - expressed as width x height. If not provided, a default is worked out automatically in the range of 32-100 so it best
> matches the raster dimensions. It is worth remembering that when
> importing multiple files, tiles will be computed for the first raster
> and then applied to others.

Alternatively you can let the script compute it for you by means of setting `-t` to `auto` e.g.

```
raster2pgsql -s 5235 -t auto -C -F file.tif public.hrsl_lka | psql -d db
```

Related answer: [Are there limitations using a PostGIS out-db raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32073)

Comment: Beautiful! That was it! I set it to auto as I don't fully understand what the tile size does, but that's what I'll try to figure out next.

Thanks so much, Jim!